# event dispatcher as a servie

Tags: java, android, service, listener, dispatcher

I would like to implement an event dispatcher for network communication. An activity should register a listener at this dispatcher using such a function:

```
void addListener(String type, Listener listener)
```

On the other hand I need such a function to request the server:

```
void request(String type, JSONObject data)
```

I decided to use a service to hold the connection and dispatch the events because of two reasons:

1. making it accessible from every activity
2. using the lifecycle that is specified for android apps

This service must not be visible to other applications so there is no need for IPC. I tried to bind a service to my activity and use an **android.os.IBinder** to create a **android.os.Messenger** for the communication. (like described here: [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)) But I guess messaging and responding to messages does not really fit to my requirements. Whats the best way to register listeners to a service and call those listeners to manipulate a view of an activity? To maybe make it more difficult: whats about using a thread for the service to avoid blocking the UI on a request? Does anyone got a clue how to do that or some good resources to investigate? 
**Thank you :)**